# Copy fields from its parent class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question regarding Java class fields.

I have two Java classes: Parent and Child

```
class Parent{
    private int a;
    private boolean b;
    private long c;

    // Setters and Getters
    .....
}


class Child extends Parent {
    private int d;
    private float e;

    // Setters and Getters
    .....
}
```

Now I have an instance of the `Parent` class. Is there any way to create an instance of the `Child` class and copy all the fields of the parent class without calling the setters one by one?

I don't want to do this:

```
   Child child = new Child();
   child.setA(parent.getA());
   child.setB(parent.getB());
   ......
```

Also, the `Parent` does not have a custom constructor and I cannot add constructor onto it.

Please give you opinions.

Many thanks.

Comment: How about overriding the parents getters and setters in the child class. Like Nambari suggests.

Answer (score 33):

Have you tried, using apache lib?

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(child, parent)
```

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. A little corection , It's actually BeanUtils.copyProperties(parent,child) or (source,target)

Comment: @sheetal Eh... no. It's `BeanUtils.copyProperties(destination, original)`: https://github.com/apache/commons-beanutils/blob/f9ac36d916bf2271929b52e9b40d5cd8ea370d4b/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.java#L132

Comment: @Jasper I guess I am using spring framework then https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

Comment: Super useful for an inverse casting... Thanks a lot.

Comment: spring also have a `BeanUtils`, the same function is in there too and work exactly the same. Use this if you already using spring.

Answer (score 7):

you can use reflection i do it and work fine for me:

```
 public Child(Parent parent){
    for (Method getMethod : parent.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (getMethod.getName().startsWith("get")) {
            try {
                Method setMethod = this.getClass().getMethod(getMethod.getName().replace("get", "set"), getMethod.getReturnType());
                setMethod.invoke(this, getMethod.invoke(parent, (Object[]) null));

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                //not found set
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1 for this. Thanks. But use .replaceFirst instead, or else you'll have trouble with method names like getTarget -- there are two 'get's to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Did you try do this due reflection? Technicaly you invoke setters one by one but you don't need to know all names of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your fields as `protected` instead of private and access them directly on the child class. Does that help?

Comment: This will not help, from the question it seems that he needs to create a new instance of Child from another instance of Parent

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Child` constructor that accepts a Parent. But there, you will have to set all the values one by one (but you can access the Child attributes directly, without set).

There is a workaround with reflection, but it only adds complication to this.
 You don't want it just for save some typing.